# Is the Visual Studio 2010 C++ linker faster with large projects?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I know it's still in beta, but I'm still really interested if anyone has seen any improvement on link times of large C++ applications.

I did some testing myself, but I didn't get very far: I only got our low-level stuff to compile and run. Mid-level stuff gave weird C++ lib errors that couldn't be fixed by a couple of hours googling and fiddling. So before I continue on this track I'd like to know if there's any chance of reducing our +- 1m30s link times.

Comment: It would be nice, but I really distrust performance measurements on pre-production software.  Frequently it gets faster, but sometimes gets slower.

Comment: I guess you're right. I guess I'll better wait till the final version is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/09/10/linker-throughput.aspx
Seems like the link time may have improved